# ProgressDialog Android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am trying to use ProgressDialog.  when i run my app the Progress Dialog box show and disappear after 1 second. I want to show it on completion of my process.. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
android.view.View.OnClickListener mSearchListenerListener;
 private ProgressDialog dialog;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      new YourCustomAsyncTask().execute(new String[] {null, null});

      }



  private class YourCustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void> { 

        protected void onPreExecute() { 
           dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); 
           dialog.setMessage("Loading...."); 
           dialog.setIndeterminate(true); 
           dialog.setCancelable(true); 
           dialog.show(); //Maybe you should call it in ruinOnUIThread in doInBackGround as suggested from a previous answer
        } 

        protected void doInBackground(String strings) { 
           try { 

            //  search(strings[0], string[1]);

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                 public void run() { 
                  //  updateMapWithResult(); //Or call it onPostExecute before progressDialog's dismiss. I believe this method updates the UI so it should run on UI thread
                 } 
               }); 

           } catch(Exception e) {
           }


        }

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Void params) { 
        dialog.dismiss(); 
        //result 

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    } 

}
}
```

Updated Question:

```
        @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        mDatabase = db;





          Log.i("PATH",""+mDatabase.getPath());



        mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);





        loadDictionary();
    }

    /**
     * Starts a thread to load the database table with words
     */
    private void loadDictionary() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadWords();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void loadWords() throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading words...");


        for(int i=0;i<=25;i++)

            {  //***// 


        final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(raw_textFiles[i]);
        //InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        try {





            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((word = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(word);
            //  Log.i("WORD in Parser", ""+word);
            }


            String contents = sb.toString();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(contents, "||");
            while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                String row = st.nextElement().toString();

                String title = row.substring(0, row.indexOf("$$$"));
                String desc = row.substring(row.indexOf("$$$") + 3);
                // Log.i("Strings in Database",""+title+""+desc);
                long id = addWord(title,desc);

                if (id < 0) {
                  Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + title);
              }
            }

        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }

        }

        Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
    }
```

I want to show ProgressDialogue box untill all words are not entered in the database. This code is in inner calss which extends SQLITEHELPER. so how to can i use ProgressDialogue in that inner class and run my addWords() method in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have this

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                 public void run() { 
                  //  updateMapWithResult(); //Or call it onPostExecute before progressDialog's dismiss. I believe this method updates the UI so it should run on UI thread
                 } 
               });
```

in your doInBackground().

Progress dialog doesn't take priority when there is some other action being performed on the main UI thread. They are intended only when the actions are done in the background. runonUIthread inside doInBackground will not help you. And this is normal behavior for the progressdialog to be visible only for few seconds.

Comment: I had the same situation and haven't found any solution yet. am sorry.

Comment: @Akhter : why you are not calling updateMapWithResult();  inside onPostExecute ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I think he wants to show a progress dialog until the view is drawn fully. So he had tried something this way.

Comment: @AndroSelva : yes but we can call  dialog.dismiss();  after updateMapWithResult(); method  inside onPostExecute

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK No my friend. It wont have any effect. It will still hang up the screen and at the time of completing the draw, the progress dialog just pops for a second and vanishes.

Comment: @AndroSelva : oh!, means inside updateMapWithResult() method Op is doing heavy task then OP must change code to run heavy task inside doInBackground and then update Ui with results. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have two `doInBackground()` methods inside your `AsyncTask` Class. Remove the `runOnUiThread()` from First `doInBackground()` and move it to second `doInBackground()` which has `@Override` annotation.

I don't know whether you wantedly written two `doInBackground()` methods or by mistake but it is not good to have such confusion between the Method. Your `AsyncTask` is not calling the first `doInBackground()` and it will call `doInBackground()` which has `@Override` annotation. So your `ProgressDialog` is dismissed in 1 second of time as it returns null immediately.

Comment: i did that but the dialogue box is dispersing in just 1 milliseconds